# Terminal repeat command, with variable, and new output name

Tags: bash, sh

I'd like to repeat the following command a number of times:

```
composite -geometry +0+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg composite001.jpg
```

Lets say I want to run this command 50 times, adding 3 to the current +0 every time, and adding 1 to the name of the output each time. How can I do this?

Comment: `for i in {0..150..3}; do composite -geometry +$i+20 ... .jpg; done`? (works only in Bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in `bash` would be to use a C-style `for` loop to iterate over the desired values of `x` (for the geometry) and `i` (to generate an output files).

```
for ((i=0, x=0; i<50; i++,x+=3)); do
    printf -v output 'composite%03d.jpg' "$x"
    composite -geometry +"$x"+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg "$output"
done
```

You can make it POSIX-compliant without too much effort, though at the cost of needing to run `printf` in a subshell.

```
i=0 x=0
while [ "$i" -lt 50 ]; do
    output=$(printf 'composite%03d.jpg' "$x")
    composite -geometry +"$x"+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg "$output"
    : $((i+=1)) $((x+=3))
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you can try this.

```
for n in {1..50}; do
   FILENAME=$(printf "composite%03d.jpg" $n)
   X=$(((n-1)*3))
   composite -geometry +$X+20 foreground.jpg background.jpg $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: There seemed to be an error in line 3, just to inform you.